# How do I save the value of an object into another variable only at a specific instance of a for loop?

Tags: python, iteration

I am currently working on a code golf problem where I have to output multiple trees of varying sizes using an asterisk. I have gotten down everything but one problem I have is that there must be a trunk at the bottom.

**reference**

```
    *
   ***
  *****
 *******
*********
    *
```

The row at the bottom must be identical to the one at the top. I created a for loop for my output, which prints all lines from the top to bottom. I wanted to know if I could return the value of my output variable at the beginning to reuse at the bottom.

If this is not possible, what else could I do as an alternative?

**Please do not answer with code, as I would like to complete it by myself. I would rather be answered with advice on what to learn.**

Edits:
General,unoptimized rundown of my code

```
def myLoop(l,character):
    global output
    for i in range(l):
        output += character

def tree(length):
    global output
    o = ''
    asterisk = 1
    while length>-1:
        myLoop(length, ' ');myLoop(asterisk, '*')
        o += '\n'
        length -= 1;asterisk += 2
        print(o)
```

Comment: "I would rather be answered with advice on what to learn." but it's still useful for us to see what code you currently have, and point out some parts of the code you may want to change, or re-use, etc.

Comment: *"I wanted to know if I could return the value of my output variable at the beginning to reuse at the bottom."*: yes this is possible, although "return" is the wrong word here.

Comment: "if I could return the value of my output variable at the beginning to reuse at the bottom" - sure, why not? You should know what "return" means, so you'll need to learn functions in Python. Or you could just save the first row in some variable and then print that variable again to complete the tree

Comment: @9769953 I won't share the entirety of the code, but I could try to give a general idea.

Comment: @ForceBru When I was saying 'Return' I wasn't using the standard Python definition, but what I meant by that was saving it to another value. I was using functions to do the entire for loop statement.

Answer (score 1):

You have few options there.

1. Create a function that gets e.g. row number and return value which should be printed. In that case you could call it twice with row number = 1
2. Remember that value in different variable. So it would be something like

```
for i in range(10):
    row = <some calculations>
    if i == 0:
        first_row = row
```